# Find the maximum value of 'AND' in a set

Tags: python

> Given a number(x) and threshold value, find the max value that can be achieved by performing `Binary AND` on all the numbers till x.The max values should be less than threshold.

Eg: If 2 , 3 is the input, then

```
A = 1 ; B = 1 ; A & B = 1
A = 1 ; B = 2 ; A & B = 0
A = 2 ; B = 1 ; A & B = 0
A = 2 ; B = 2 ; A & B = 2
```

In this example the maximum value that I got from the `AND` operation is 2 and it is less than the threshold value 3 so 2 is the answer that should be printed.

I have to find the max values from all these possible inputs and then print them. I solved this problem with this code

```
maxValue = 0
n,k1 = input().strip().split(' ')
n,k1 = [int(n),int(k1)]
for j in range (1,n):
    for k in range (j+1,n):
        jkValue = j&k
        if jkValue > maxValue and jkValue < k1:
            maxValue = jkValue
print(maxValue)
```

From my previous experiences with problems like this I could solve this more efficiently if I use some kind of data structure like `list`,`map`.

Is it possible to solve this problem using data structures or have I achieved the minimum complexity? If it can be made better then how?

Comment: this is probably minimum complexity. if you used something like `item in list`, it still runs a for loop inside a for loop.

Comment: Your problem statement is unintelligible. The "on all the numbers till that before and the max values should be less than threshold" part makes no grammatical sense.

Comment: The question is quite hard to understand. Are you trying to find `max(i&j such that 0 < i < j < n and i&j < k1)`?

Comment: @PaulHankin I have added an example for more clarity...Check the problem now

Comment: Your example admits A=B as a solution, but your code doesn't. If you allow the two numbers being and-ed to be the same, the answer is min(n, k-1).

Comment: I'm with Paul. Use pen & paper, not code, for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem is to find `0<i<j<n` that maximizes `i&j` such that `i&j<k`.

You can find the answer by constructing the result bit by bit. Starting from high bits, you figure out if there's two numbers with the highest bits already determined by previous steps, and both have the current bit set, such that they're both in range, and their bitwise and is less than `k`.

This runs in O(log `k`) time (or more precisely, it performs O(log `k`) arithmetic operations).

```
# max_and returns the max i&j subject to:
# 0 < i < j < n and i&j < k.
def max_and(n, k):
    r = 0
    b = 1
    while b < k:
        b <<= 1
    while b:
        # Can we set bit b in the result?
        # We can't if r|b >= k.
        # Otherwise, are there two numbers greater than or equal to r,
        # and less than n, both with bit b set?
        # The two smallest numbers greater than or equal to r with
        # bit b set are r|b and ((r|b) + 1) | (r|b). We need only
        # test the latter against n.
        if (r | b) | ((r | b) + 1) < n and r|b < k:
            r |= b
        b >>= 1
    return r
```

Here's a simple and obviously correct solution that runs in O(n^2) time, and some tests that the efficient version produces the same results for small n and k.

```
def max_and_slow(n, k):
    return max(i&j for i in xrange(n) for j in xrange(i+1, n) if i&j < k)

for n in xrange(2, 20):
    for k in xrange(1, 20):
        mas = max_and_slow(n, k)
        ma = max_and(n, k)
        if ma != mas:
            print 'max_and(%d, %d) = %d, want %d' % (n, k, ma, mas)
```